# Integral curves for non-autonomous vector field that depends on a parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm reading the chapter about dynamical systems in J. E. Marden and T. Ratiu's *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications*.

After stating and proving the existence theorems for autonomous ODEs (i.e., every vector field $ X\colon U\subset E\to E $ has a unique in-some-sense-local integral curve, where $ E $ is any Banach space), the authors remark that the same theorem holds if the vector field $ X $ depends on "time" and on another parameter $ \rho $.

I'm familiar with non-autonomous vector fields. But let's suppose that $ X\colon U\times \mathbb R\times V\to E $ is a vector field defined on some open sets $ U\subset E $, $ V\subset F $, where $ E $ is the ambient Banach space and $ F $ is another Banach space of "parameters" $ \rho $.

What is an integral curve for $ X $? Is it just a curve $ \gamma\colon J\times V \to U $ defined on some open interval such that
$$
\dot\gamma(t,\rho) = X(\gamma(t,\rho),t,\rho)
$$
for any $ t\in J $ and $ \rho\in V $?

Comment: Yes that’s essentially it. But regarding terminology, for a fixed $\rho$, it is the single curve $\gamma(\cdot,\rho)$ that I would call *an integral curve of $X$*, or more properly,  notice how if you fix $\rho$ then $X(\cdot,\cdot,\rho)$ is a time-dependent vector field in the usual sense and $\gamma(\cdot,\rho)$ is an integral curve of this vector field. You can then of course consider the full parameter-dependent flow to generalize the usual flow.